# Set a specific "consumer" param through user agent in nextjs

Tags: javascript, http, next.js, user-agent, plyr.js

I'm working on a VOD project with next.js, 
It has a /play page which is only a video player (Plyr React Component)
This VOD website's contents are available in some other applications, and when a user visits our website from another application, it passes a query param named "consumer" which contains the name of the application which serves our content on its application.
I was told I should pass the consumer through user-agent to the server to track down the used traffic. How can I send this consumer param through user-agent on the player?